# Raspberry Pi 4 pip install opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I try to install opencv on my raspberry pi 4

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I get the following error

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
>   Collecting opencv-python
>     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python

I use 2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-full

```
$ python -V
```

> Python 3.7.3

```
$ pip --version
```

> pip 19.2.1 from
>   /home/pi/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

I saw some recommended ways, but none of them work:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94990/installation-of-opencv-contrib-python-through-pip3-fails

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.4.19
```

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/

```
$ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-100
$ sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test python3-pyqt5
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev

pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

I remember that it always worked on my other raspberry pis (2b and 3).
Is there an option to install opencv on the raspberry pi 4?

Comment: 'pip install opencv-python-aarch64' try

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is also not working:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install opencv-python-aarch64
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python-aarch64
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python-aarch64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python-aarch64

Comment: Is your network behind the proxy server ???

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem since Sunday with my Raspberry Pi 3B and the current Raspbian version.

Under Python 2.7 the installation is done, but with a noise in the images, which didn't occur before.

PS: I had to completely reinstall Raspbian on Sunday due to an SD card problem.

Versions:

```
Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software
Image with desktop and recommended software based on Debian Buster
Version:July 2019
Release date:2019-07-10
Kernel version:4.19

Python 3.7.3

PIP 19.2.1
```

current numpy package is installed

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use this script on raspberry pi with buster version of raspbian.

First of all , to use below code you have to make opencv41.sh file and put this code in **opencv41.sh** file. put this file in home.*run using **bash opencv41.sh** in terminal. keep in mind that you should go to home directory first and then open the terminal and put this command.Let me know if it works.

> bash opencv41.sh

```
    sudo apt-get -y update
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade
    sudo apt-get -y install screen
    sudo apt-get -y install htop


    # substitute string1 for string2 globally
    sudo sed -i 's/CONF_SWAPSIZE=100/CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048/g' /etc/dphys-swapfile

    sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
    sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start

    sudo sed -i '$a gpu_mem=128' /boot/config.txt

    sudo apt-get -y install build-essential cmake pkg-config
    sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
    sudo apt-get -y install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
    sudo apt-get -y install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
    sudo apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
    sudo apt-get -y install libatlas-base-dev gfortran

    sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev

    wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.1.0.zip

    wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.1.0.zip

    unzip opencv.zip
    unzip opencv_contrib.zip

    # yes you really need to rename the directories
    mv opencv-4.1.0/ opencv
    mv opencv_contrib-4.1.0/ opencv_contrib

    # you have to make python3.6 env so it uses python3.6 for the build
    mkdir -p .virtualenvs
    python3 -m venv .virtualenvs/cv2_env
    source .virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/activate

    # took a really long time
    pip3 install numpy

    cd ~/opencv
    mkdir build
    cd build

    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
    -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..

    make -j4

    sudo make install
    sudo ldconfig
    sudo apt-get update

    cd ~/opencv/build/lib/python3
    mkdir -p ~/lib/cv2
    cp cv2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so ~/lib/cv2
    ln -s ~/lib/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so ~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.so

    cd ~

    # update /etc/dphys-swapfile to increase size
    # set CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
    # set CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048
    sudo sed -i 's/CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048/CONF_SWAPSIZE=100/g' /etc/dphys-swapfile

    sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
    sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start

    # update /boot/config.txt
    sudo sed -i 's/gpu_mem=128/gpu_mem=16/g' /boot/config.txt

    rm opencv.zip
    rm opencv_contrib.zip

    sudo rm -r opencv
    sudo rm -r opencv_contrib

    # to test
    # source ~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/activate
    # python
    # import cv2
    # print(cv2.__version__)
    # you should see 4.1.0
```

Comment: -1 for not referencing the source you copied all of this from (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/16/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-raspbian-buster )